# How to avoid naming colisions in resource names?

Tags: chef-recipe

I just had an error in my recipe because i had an resource with the same name in another recipe. I had a execute resource named 'download-package' resource in both recipes...

How can i avoid naming collisions in chef recipes?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no magical way for this and a report handler won't be able to report resource duplication (but I may be wrong here, anyone with better knowledge is welcome to confirm/infirm this statement)

The best you can do is running test with vagrant isolated boxes and fix the Warnings when necessary ...

I think you may already check this with chefspec/berkshelf as the converge will raise this kine of warnings, it involves mocking the runlist with chefspec (with a role or something like that)

Here is a great blog about how to test cookbooks https://micgo.net/
Chefspec doc is here: https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec

Hope it will help you